# nextauth signIn not creating user in Firebase Authentication

Tags: firebase, next-auth

I am currently using NextAuth + Firebase Authentication for my app. The code below handles authentication and user session perfectly, but I noticed it's not actually creating the user that is listed under Firebase Authentication; which means I cannot track firebase's natively-built DAU and other metrics.

I already checked out this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#node.js_4), but I am not exactly sure how this applies for nextAuth specifically. Would appreciate if anyone shared their experience!

`LoginButton.tsx`:

```js
import { useSession, signIn, signOut } from 'next-auth/react';

const ScraftIcon = () => {
  const { data: session } = useSession();

  return (
    <Tooltip title="Log In">
      <button
        onClick={() => signIn('google')}
      >
        <MdLogin size="30" />
      </button>
    </Tooltip>
  );
};

export default ScraftIcon;
```

`[...nextauth].ts`:

```js
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";
import { FirestoreAdapter } from "@next-auth/firebase-adapter";
import { cert } from "firebase-admin/app";
import "firebase/firestore";

export const authOptions = {
  // Configure one or more authentication providers
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID!,
      clientSecret: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET!,
    }),
    // ...add more providers here
  ],
  adapter: FirestoreAdapter({
    credential: cert({
      projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
      clientEmail: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_CLIENT_EMAIL,
      privateKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY,
    }),
  }),
};
export default NextAuth(authOptions);
```

Comment: Your code doesn't much match the example you see in the [documentation](https://authjs.dev/reference/adapter/firebase#example-1). It's missing a lot of stuff.  You're not using `FirestoreAdapter` anywhere here.

Comment: @DougStevenson thanks for the feedback! I just updated the post with firestoreadapter added. The authentication now works in both local and production but I'm still not seeing new user created. Can you suggest me anything I should try?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, user is created in firestore but not in the User Authentication part. Did you find a solution to the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue, so looking around the web led me to this discussion on GitHub. I think the answer provided here would solve your issue: https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/discussions/7157

Following this method, you need to generate a custom token, add it to the session, and on the client-side, retrieve the token from the session and use it to sign in to Firebase.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're facing is that NextAuth is handling the authentication flow and storing the user in your Firestore database using the Firestore adapter, but it's not actually interacting with Firebase Authentication to create the user there.

NextAuth and Firebase Authentication are two distinct authentication mechanisms. While both can utilize OAuth providers like Google, they handle user management differently.

To have the user registered in Firebase Authentication as well, you'll need to manually use Firebase's SDK to create or sign in the user after the NextAuth authentication process.

Here's a potential solution:

1.**Initialize Firebase in Your App:**

If you haven't already, initialize Firebase in your Next.js application. You can do this in a separate file and then import it wherever you need.

```js
    // firebase.js
    import firebase from 'firebase/app';
    import 'firebase/auth';

    if (!firebase.apps.length) {
       firebase.initializeApp({
          apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
          authDomain: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
          projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
          // ... other firebase config
       });
    }

    export default firebase;
```

**2.Handle Firebase Authentication After NextAuth Authentication:**

After NextAuth completes the authentication, use the Firebase SDK to sign in the user with the same provider.

```js
import { useSession, signIn as nextAuthSignIn } from 'next-auth/react';
import firebase from './path-to-firebase.js';

const ScraftIcon = () => {
   const { data: session } = useSession();

   const handleSignIn = async () => {
      await nextAuthSignIn('google');
      if (!firebase.auth().currentUser) {
         const googleProvider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
         await firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(googleProvider);
      }
   };

   return (
      <Tooltip title="Log In">
         <button onClick={handleSignIn}>
            <MdLogin size="30" />
         </button>
      </Tooltip>
   );
};

export default ScraftIcon;
```

**3.Considerations:**

By adding this step, you're essentially signing the user in twice: once with NextAuth and once with Firebase Authentication. This could lead to slightly longer sign-in times.

Make sure to handle sign-out similarly, ensuring the user is signed out from both NextAuth and Firebase Authentication.

This approach ensures that users are stored in both Firestore (through the NextAuth adapter) and Firebase Authentication. If you need to synchronize user data between the two, you'll need additional logic.
while this approach ensures users are registered in Firebase Authentication, it's important to test and ensure that the dual sign-in process doesn't introduce any unexpected behaviors in your application.

while this approach ensures users are registered in Firebase Authentication, it's important to test and ensure that the dual sign-in process doesn't introduce any unexpected behaviors in your application.