# next-auth with Google provider and Firebase does not create a user in authentication

Tags: firebase, next.js, next-auth

I have configured next-auth with Firebase in `api/auth/[...nextauth].js` as follows:

```js
import {FirestoreAdapter} from "@auth/firebase-adapter"
import {cert} from "firebase-admin/app"
import NextAuth from "next-auth"
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google"
export const authOptions = {
  // Configure one or more authentication providers
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    }
    ),
  ],
  adapter: FirestoreAdapter({
    credential: cert({
      projectId: process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
      clientEmail: process.env.FIREBASE_CLIENT_EMAIL,
      privateKey: process.env.FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY.replace(/\\n/g, '\n')
    })
  })

}

export default NextAuth(authOptions)
```

And I added all the environment variables, Google etc

On the client I'm using the `signIn` function like so:

```js
<button onClick={() => signIn('google')}
                      
                    >
                        <FcGoogle className=" w-10 h-10" />
</button>
```

Which once clicked I'm able to sign in successfully and `users`, `sessions`,`accounts` collections are created in Firestore successfully, but there is no record in Firebase authentication. My question is why is this happening and how can I solve this?

### Update

I found a similar question [nextauth-signin-not-creating-user-in-firebase-authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76375532/nextauth-signin-not-creating-user-in-firebase-authentication) with no answers.

Comment: I have the same question, did you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `signInWithCredential` to link, in your next-auth `signIn` callback:

```
const firebaseApp = initializeApp(__FIREBASE_CONFIG__);
const firebaseAuth = getAuth(firebaseApp);

 callbacks: {
    signIn: async ({ user, account, profile, email, credentials }) => {

      if (account?.provider === 'google') {
         signInWithCredential(
            firebaseAuth,
            GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
              account.id_token,
              account.access_token
            )
          );
        return true;
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. You save me. Not sure why this answer is not accepted yet :D